# Flutter Firebase how to query a collection ordered by indexes of a List

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this List with document Ids as Strings;
And i want to query a collection in Cloud Firestore that returns this documents in the order of myRecipes list;

```
List myRecipes= ['N1UXCMR0flbBg6mfvimB','1UXvdsffR0flbBg6mfvimB','mcmXCMR0flbBg6mfvimB'];

StreamBuilder(
        stream:  Firestore.instance
                  .collection('recipes')
                  .where(FieldPath.documentId,
                      whereIn: myLRecipes)
                  .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          }
          return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['recipeName']),
                ;
              });
        });
```

When i run this it returns the recipes in the order of Firestore but i want to return them how they are in myRecipes list, so the first Text widget displayed will be the myRecipes[0].

I' ve also tried with the listen() method but it gives me this error

type '_ForwardingStreamSubscription<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'

Please help me i' ve been trying for days

```
List myRecipes= ['N1UXCMR0flbBg6mfvimB','1UXvdsffR0flbBg6mfvimB','mcmXCMR0flbBg6mfvimB'];

StreamBuilder(
        stream:  Firestore.instance
                  .collection('recipes')
                  .where(FieldPath.documentId,
                      whereIn: myLRecipes)
                  .snapshots().listen((event) {
            event.documents.sort((a, b) {
              return a.documentID
                  .indexOf(myRecipes.first)
                  .compareTo(myRecipes.last);
            });
          }),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          }
          return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['recipeName']),
                ;
              });
        });
```

I tried with transform but i don't know how to use it properly. Here my code

```
List myRecipes= ['N1UXCMR0flbBg6mfvimB','1UXvdsffR0flbBg6mfvimB','mcmXCMR0flbBg6mfvimB'];

StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('products')
                .where(FieldPath.documentId,
                    whereIn: snapshot.data.data['favorites'].toList())
                .snapshots()
                .transform(StreamTransformer.fromBind((event) {
          event.listen((event) {
            return event.documents.sort((a, b) {
              return a.documentID
                  .indexOf(myRecipes.first)
                  .compareTo(myRecipes.last);
            });
          });
        })));
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          }
          return GridView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['recipeName']),
                ;
              });
        });
```

This does not give me an error but it does not return any widget.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to retrieve the documents in the order that you have them in a client-side list. You'll have to reorder the documents in your application code after they've been retrieved.

Comment: And how can i do that ?

Comment: If you `listen()` to the `snapshots()`, you get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) with a [`List<DocumentSnapshot>`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/documents.html). You can reorder those and return that. If you get stuck while imeplementing this, edit your question to show the code fhtat you tried.

Comment: If you get stuck while implementing this, edit your question to show the code that you tried.

Comment: I' ve edited it (thanks a lot for your help and your patience puf!)

Comment: I think you need a `transform` instead of a listen, as your code transforms the data from a `QuerySnapshot` to a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`. The code that does the sorting can remain the same (assuming the actual sort is what you want), but you'll need to return the result of `event.documents.sort(...)` (hence the need to use `transform`)..

Comment: I would be really grateful Puf if you could be a little more specific. Thanks again for your patience

Comment: transform: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#transform-function

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? I can't figure out how to do that.